# Using a generic style as base vs custom user control

Tags: wpf, button, styles, custom-controls

I'm creating a resource dictionary to my application, where I'll have some "icon+text" buttons. Since they will all look the same (except for the icon and the text), I've created a generic style to serve as base to the others:

```
<!-- Generic ActionButtonStyle -->
<Style x:Key="ActionButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <!-- some setter properties -->
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource ButtonDataTemplate}"/>
</Style>
<DataTemplate x:Key="ButtonDataTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="24" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image  Source="{Binding Source}"
                Stretch="Uniform" 
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="2"/>
        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding text}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Margin="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

And I have some images for the icons:

```
<!-- Icons -->
  <ImageSource x:Key="textToSpeech">Images/GreyIcons/TextToSpeech.png</ImageSource>
  <ImageSource x:Key="play">Images/GreyIcons/Play.png</ImageSource>
  <ImageSource x:Key="playSound">Images/GreyIcons/PaySound.png</ImageSource>
    .
    .
    .
    .
  <ImageSource x:Key="group">Images/GreyIcons/Goup1.png</ImageSource>
```

And I'd like to create individual styles for each button (corresponding to each icon). Something like this:

```
<!-- Specific ActionButtonStyles -->
<Style x:Key="TextToSpeechButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ActionButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Content">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Image Source="{StaticResource textToSpeech}"
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I know that this doesn't work.. How should I do it? Should I create a custom user control for the generic button? The text will be binding to an object in my Model, and so will the command (to an action).

Answer (score 1):

The example of what you are looking for seems to be missing, but it seems that you may be looking for "BasedOn" - which allows you to inherit, but still override a previously defined style. You can implement it like this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ActionButtonStyle}">
  <Setter.../>
</Style>
```

Comment: I know that, but what setter should I use? (Some code was missing, I've just updated my question)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a derived class from Button that adds two new DependancyProperties. They would be called something like Text and ImageSource. Your derived class would also set the ContentTemplate as you have indicated. This ContentTemplate would bind against the Text and ImageSource dependancy properties.

You can then create your custom control in XAML like this...

```
<app:CustomButton Text="Play" Source="{Binding play}"/>
```

...but if you want the same button over and over again you could create a style that is applied to the CustomButton and sets those two properties as required.